# Test if two BSTs are equal in Java

Tags: java, equality, binary-search-tree

I would like to test if two given `BSTs` (Binary Search Trees) are equal in Java. The `BST` nodes do not have pointers to the parent nodes.

The simplest solution is to traverse both `BSTs`, create two traversal lists and test if the lists are equal. However it requires O(N) memory.

I would like to try another way: create an `Iterator`, which traverses the `BSTs`, and ... the rest is obvious.

Does it make sense? Is there any "better" (simpler and efficient) solution to test if two `BSTs` are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a recursive `equals()` method. It would require no memory, and would be easy to code.

Something like this should work:

```
public class Node {

    Object value;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Node) {
            Node node = (Node)o;
            if (value.equals(node.value)) {
                return true;
            }
            return ((left == null && node.left == null) || left.equals( node.left)) && 
                    ((right == null && node.right == null) || right.equals( node.right));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that you should override `hashCode()` to reflect this implementation, so consider naming the above impl as `equalsDeep()` instead and skipping the `hashCode()` impl.

Comment: Recursive solution _does_ require non-constant memory (the stack).

Comment: Yeah, but no heap, which I think was what the OP meant. Unless the tree is very deep (1000's of levels), this impl will be OK

Answer (score 7):

1. Binary search tree is a tree, right?
2. Two trees are equal if they have the same root and the same children.
3. Each child is also a tree.
4. See point 2.

Hint: [recursion](/questions/tagged/recursion). The memory consumption is `O(logn)` (prove it yourself).

Comment: Thanks, great. What if want a non-recursive solution ?

Comment: @Michael: You can turn recursive solution into non-recursive solution with an explicit stack.

Comment: @nhahtdh That's correct. Will it be different from the solution with `Iterators` I mentioned in the original question?

Comment: @Michael: Assuming *balanced* BST, then it will use `O(log n)` memory (otherwise, the memory can go up to `O(n)` for a skewed tree). Tomasz's method consider 2 BST equals if they have the same structure and data. If you use `Iterator`, if you mix and match BST with (doubly?) linked list, you can just use the Iterator O(1) space and compare 2 BST (by structure + data or by data only are both possible)

Comment: @Michael: it will. The maximum depth of this stack will be `log(n)` - you'll never store all nodes in one list. It's a difference between BFS and DFS traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way could be, create a hash of both tree and then check whether they are equal or not. This only apply if the content of both tree are same as well.

How to create checksum and then compare those checksum.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-a-file-checksum-value-in-java/

Comment: Hash (in Java terms) is not guaranteed to be different for two different objects. Hash (in crypthographic terms) is a bit far fetched, IMHO.

Comment: Ohhh okay, learnt something new. I will delete this answer soon. But it's an option at-least if you are comparing two hash of lets say a String object. Am I right?

Comment: @Owl I think Tomasz is referring to object.hashCode() - if you in fact mean some kind of checksum (MD5, SHA1, etc) then I think you'd be fine.